# How to Show Only Current Month in android Calendar view

Tags: java, android, calendar

Show Only Current month in Calendar View Android (or) Either Disable the Scroll View in Calendar View .......

Code for Displaying Calendar that i have written

```
<CalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:showWeekNumber="false"
       android:shownWeekCount="5" 
       android:scrollbars="none"/>
```

How Can I Show Only Current Month.....?Please Help Me Guys Thanks In Adcance.

Comment: did you achieve what u were trying to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whithin your class you can show all the way up to the end of the current month with:

```
//get month and get how many days in current month
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int daysInMonth = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
cal.setMaxDate(daysInMonth);
```

I don't beleive your `android:scrollbars="none"` is doing anything for you.

You could also try something like this  [one](http://droidwalk.blogspot.com/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html) .

Comment: still shows multiple months but this code causes the calendar to start from 1969.